# Undefined method 'posts' inside controller - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am getting error for undefined method which is defined inside my User model.
My controller:

```
$inputs = request()->validate([
    'title' => 'required|min:8|max:255',
    'post_image' => 'file',
    'body' => 'required'
    ]);
    auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
```

My Post model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

My User model:

```
   public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}
```

Comment: auth()->user->posts()->create($inputs);

Comment: when you report an error message, be sure to provide the full error message - not your interpretation of it.  The error also includes information about the file and line number

Comment: Sorry, this is message: Undefined method 'posts'. intelephense(1013) [Ln 44, Col 29]

Comment: ah ok, so this is not a php error, this is your code editor underlining the code?

Comment: Try `composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

Comment: This is a message inside "PROBLEMS" in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

correct your relationship

```
   public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Could you be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

First your posts relationship is wrong, it must be **hasMany** NOT belongsTo

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Then it should work.

You can also try to create the model in a different way:

```php
$validated = request()->validate([
    'title' => 'required|min:8|max:255',
    'post_image' => 'file',
    'body' => 'required'
]);

// Here you should check if $validated has all required fields
// because some could fail, in that case aren't in the array

Post::create([
  'title' => $validated['title'],
  'user_id' => auth()->id, // or auth()->user->id
  'post_image' => $validated['post_image'],
  'body' => $validated['body'],
]);
```

[Laravel Validation Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation)

Comment: It still doesn't work. The warning has been removed, but when I want to add a post, it does not send it to the database.

Comment: There should be an error somewhere else, check /framework/logs/laravel.log, if something there comment it here!